# Ordering a Dictionary

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, duplicates

I am adding information to a dictionary using this code:

```
foreach (string word in lineList)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
        dictionary[word]++;
    else
        dictionary[word] = 1;
}

// I believe this is what needs to change..?
var ordered = from k in dictionary.Keys select k;
```

When I use the `StreamWriter` to print out the lines it is printing it out in the order it was added to the `dictionary`.

What I am trying to do is print it out in an order that first compares the `PartDescription`and then the `PartNumber` and prints it out numerically.

the File looks like this:

```
PartDescription        PartNumber        Name        X        Y        Rotation
1608RTANT              147430            J1        20.555   -12.121       180
TANTD                  148966            J2        20.555   -12.121       270
SOMETHING              148966            R111      20.555   -12.121       360
SOMETHING              148966            C121      20.555   -12.121       180
SOMETHING              148966            R50       205.555  -12.121       180
SOMETHING              148966            R51      -205.555  125.121       270
SOMETHING              148966            R52       20.555   -12.121       0
SOMETHING              148966            C12       20.555   -12.121       0
1709RTANT              147430            C98       20.555   -12.121       0
1608RTANT              147429            QD1       20.555   -12.121       180
1709RTANT              147430            F12       20.555   -12.121       0
1609RTANT              147445            P9        20.555   -12.121       180
```

The `StreamWriter` would output like this:

```
1, 1608RTANT, 147429, 1   //Line#, PartDescription, PartNumber, # of Duplicates (from dictionary key)
2, 1608RTANT, 147430, 1
3, 1609RTANT, 147445, 1
4, 1709RTANT, 147430, 2
5, SOMETHING, 148966, 6
6, TANTD, 148966, 1
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could use SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.  It's slightly slower than Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, as SD is O(log 2 n) and D is O(1), but it will always keep your data in sorted order.  Just depends on which is more important to your usage: fastest lookup possible or keeping data in order.  If you're just sorting it once for output, just sort as suggested.  I just wanted to throw out the other option just in case you needed the data in order in multiple places, then the cost of sorting could potentially add up and make SD worth the slightly slower lookup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you could certainly get the keys in an ordered way easily:

```
var ordered = from k in dictionary.Keys orderby k select k;
```

Or even more simply:

```
var ordered = dictionary.Keys.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Note that you shouldn't *rely* on the dictionary storing the pairs in the order in which you added them - basically you shouldn't assume *any* ordering out of the dictionary.

Comment: @theNoobGuy: Your updated code isn't obviously related to the original code - there's no sign of the ordering. Please post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok I added how I am populating the List... does that help?

Comment: @theNoobGuy: Not really - it's not a short but complete program, and you still haven't shown where you're trying to use an ordered view of the keys. I'm off to bed, but if you post a short but complete example (hint: we should be able to cut/paste/compile/run with no more work), maybe someone else will be able to help more.